# A question about convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are a sequence of continuous and bounded random variables such that $X_n \xrightarrow{D} X$, then does it hold that $\lfloor X_n \rfloor \xrightarrow{D} \lfloor X \rfloor$?

Here $X$ is also a continuous random variable and $\xrightarrow{D}$ stands for convergence in distribution.

My attempt: Since $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ has discontinuities at only countable points and since $X_n$ are all bounded, I think the result directly follows from Portmanteau theorem. But I am unable to apply it rigorously and argue. Can some one help?

Comment: No -- consider $X_n$ uniform on $(1-\frac2n,1-\frac1n)$, then $X_n\to1$ in distribution but $\lfloor X_n\rfloor=0$ with full probability, for every $n\geqslant2$.

Comment: Oops. So, my comment is misleading, in light of @Did's comment (hard to prove something that is false). Will delete it.

Comment: @ClementC. Wait, "my" $X$ is not continuous... :-)

Comment: Fair enough (but whether what I suggested -- using the definition of convergence in distribution as pointwise convergence of the cdf where it's continuous -- can work in the setting where $X$ is also continuous, I definitely hadn't thought of your example... so if my suggestion works, it's coincidental, not due to good thinking :))

Comment: @ClementC. : Isn't the above counterexample false since $X=1$ is not continuous? Can you post your answer?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon Just did. Consider doublechecking carefully, I am a bit rusty (and, more importantly, completely sleep-deprived). Also, I switched from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as I was not sure how to interpret the floor function there (componentwise?).

Comment: @ClementC.: Yes, componentwise indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the definition of convergence in distribution: letting $F_n$ (resp $F$) be the cumulative distribution function of $X_n$ (resp. $X$), we have
$$
F_n(x) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} F(x)
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F$ is continuous. Since $X$ is a continuous r.v., this is everywhere.

Now, consider any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X_n\rfloor \leq x\}
&=
\mathbb{P}\{ X_n < \lfloor x\rfloor + 1\}
\\&=
\mathbb{P}\{ X_n \leq \lfloor x\rfloor + 1\}\tag{$X_n$ is continuous}
\\&=
F_n(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1).
\end{align}$$
By assumption, this converges, when $n\to\infty$, to 
$F(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)$
which, by the same chain of equalities (but for $X$) is equal to $\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X\rfloor \leq x\}$. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X_n\rfloor \leq x\} 
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 
\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X\rfloor \leq x\}
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, showing the convergence in law.

Comment: +1, but note that $\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X_n\rfloor \leq x\}=F_n(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)$.

Comment: How does $\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor X_n\rfloor \leq \lfloor x\rfloor\}
=
\mathbb{P}\{ \lfloor x\rfloor \leq X_n < \lfloor x\rfloor + 1\}$ hold? $X_n$ can lie in any integer interval $[a,a+1)$ where $a \leq \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks! @Did

Comment: @pikachuchameleon It does not hold -- this was a mistake.

Comment: @ClementC.: Does the same proof hold for $\mathbb{R}^d$ as well?

Comment: I would think so, everything used here should immediately generalize. Again, I have never seen the floor function used on $\mathbb{R}^d$ as componentwise  floor function, so I preferred not to use it that way -- but it should be a matter of minutes to check if everything above does go through.